# Ansible : use a fact variable with a dictionary variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I would like to install Apache on several linux server. Apache package has not the same name on RedHat or Debian operating system (apache2 vs httpd): Is it a way to use an ansible fact variable ("ansible_os_family") as a key of a dictionary variable ?

Something like that (but this doesn't work) :

```
---
- name: playbook1
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars:
    apache_packages: {
      "RedHat": "httpd",
      "Debian": "apache2"
      }
  tasks:
    - name: Install Apache server
      package:
        name:  "{{ apache_packages['{{ ansible_os_family }}']  }}"
        state: present
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting Jinja delimiters inside another Jinja delimiter is **never** a good idea.

> Another rule is ‘moustaches don’t stack’. We often see this:
>
> ```yaml
> {{ somevar_{{other_var}} }}
> ```
>
> The above DOES NOT WORK as you expect, if
> you need to use a dynamic variable use the following as appropriate:
>
> ```yaml
> {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['somevar_' + other_var] }}
> ```
>
> For ‘non host vars’ you can use the [vars lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/vars_lookup.html#vars-lookup) plugin:
>
> ```yaml
> {{ lookup('vars', 'somevar_' + other_var) }}
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names*</sup>

If you don't surround something with quotes, it will be assumed as being a variable, so in this case, this is as simple as:

```yaml
name:  "{{ apache_packages[ansible_os_family] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: you define packages as a dict of list (based on os family)

```
- name: playbook1
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  vars:
    packages:
      debian:
        - apache2
      redhat:
        - httpd
  tasks:
    - name: Install Apache server
      package:
        name:  "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      loop: "{{ packages.get(ansible_os_family|lower) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do some thing like below to reduce the lines

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes 
  tasks:
  - package:
      name: "{{ 'apache2' if ansible_os_family == 'Debian' else ('httpd' if ansible_os_family == 'RedHat') }}"
      state: present
```